# Change Table Cell Height to match contents with Chosen

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using the [chosen script by harvest](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), and on a couple of pages I'm using a `Multiple Select`. When you have selected some options, the select box grows in height. The only issue is that I have this is in a table cell which doesn't grow with it :/

Unfortunately the code is in a locked site and it's not easy to duplicate for a demo, but if you go to the chosen site (linked above) and try one of the multi selects you'll see how it grows when selecting multiple items.

I've tried to put it in a div in the table cell and cleared it, but it still goes over the cell.

I've also tried `inline-block`, and `height:auto` on the cell, but nothing :(

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could make the cell height grow with the content?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try `position:relative;` for chosen box

Comment: @TamilSelvan and do what else? I've added that but nothing happens. What option am I matching it with?

Comment: how about `height:auto` and `overflow:auto` together?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hmm, that sort of worked, but then the select options went under the cell and was cut off :/ looks like it's going to be more complicated than I thought

Comment: Without seeing any code is tough to know, but I'm guessing you have some floating element there. Try removing the `float` (if possible), and see if that works

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no code modifications to original which can be seen at http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select

Comment: How about the CSS? compare the css applied to your cell and box, to the one in the cell/box of Chosen examples page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64208/discussion-between-dpdesignz-and-alvaro-montoro).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro the examples on that page are in floated `divs` :(